# How to use the example membership module from MVC4 with codefirst created database?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, sql-server-express, membership

I'm working on a MVC4 project with MS SQL Server Express database.

Here is what I did:

I started a MVC4 project in which the membership module is included (AccountsController.cs, AccountModel.cs and view files)

Next I added some models, controllers, a context and an initializer to seed some test data. Using ef-codefirst, this created my context.mdf database which works fine.

The problem I'm having is that I now have 2 databases. The one from the standard membership module, and the one created with ef-codefirst. 
I cannot seem to find out how I can use the membership module, to work with the database that is created from my ef-codefirst because I need everything to be in 1 database.

I've been searching all day for examples or a solution in which the ready to go membership module from the mvc4 template is used in combination with a code first created database but after all these hours I lost track of what to do and what not to so hopefully anyone got some tips.

Answer (score 0):

So after another week of stress the problem I was having turned out to be because of Migrations. 
**With migrations enabled you can only use 1 database context class.** 
I started out without migrations, then created the database tables with EF and seeded data to them with an initilizer. Next I added migrations, added everything from my own context to the existing context from the template membership module and then nothing worked anymore. Migrations wasn't creating any tables or modifying any.
So I started a new project, with only 1 context class and migrations, and everything worked fine.